# Help with simple restful post problem

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, post

I am new to restful services and I have been creating a series of simple console apps to better understand.  I have a simlple service that I am trying to send data to but I keep getting a 400 bad request error.  I know it has to be something simple I overlooked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
//service contract
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Test")]
bool Test(string input);

//service
public bool Test(string input)
{
   Console.Out.WriteLine("recieved [" + input + "]");
   return true;
}

//host program
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8889/TestImage");
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ImageTestService), baseAddress);

        try   
        {   
            host.Open();

            Console.Out.WriteLine("TestService hosted at {0}", baseAddress.ToString());
            Console.Out.WriteLine("hit enter to terminate");
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (host.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                host.Abort();
            else
                host.Close();
        }   
    }
}

//client program
// Create the web request
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8889/TestImage/Test");
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

// Set type to POST   
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.Append("input=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("12345"));

// Create a byte array of the data we want to send   
byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

// Set the content length in the request headers   
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

// Write data   
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
   postStream.Close();
}

// Get response   
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   // Get the response stream   
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is answers your question - but I have an extension method I have been using for form post:

```
    public static HttpWebResponse DoFormPost(this HttpWebRequest request, string postVals, int timeoutSeconds)
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = timeoutSeconds * 0x3e8;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postVals);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Or since you tagged WCF, then there is also another similar question:

[Getting an http 400 error on calling a restful wcf service using http post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325013/getting-an-http-400-error-on-calling-a-restful-wcf-service-using-http-post)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, it looks okay at first glance.  I wonder if it's the UriTemplate that you're using.  If your method is "Test" and the UriTemplate is "Test", you might need to call it with this URL (two "Test" strings):

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8889/TestImage/Test/Test");
```

I believe the method name is part of the URL by default, so the template gets applied after that.

With HTTP errors, I use a tool called Fiddler to troubleshoot.  If you can create a request that works with the Request Builder, it's just a matter of figuring out how to produce that request via your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried your suggestion and added another "Test" to the URL but I got a 404 .  I installed Fiddler and I can see what I am sending to the service but it all looks fine to me.  If the server method has an argument named "input" do I have to include the parm naem in the post string or do I only do that if the parm nameis in the URL template?

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service you are calling is expecting the string you are passing to be serialized in XML!

The following has worked for me in the past:

```
string body = "foo";
string postData = @"<string xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'><![CDATA[" + body + "]]></string>";
```